# Included rounded medians in a box plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

So I know how to include the medians but I can’t seem to figure out how to round them.

This is what I have so far (if I mess up with how I include the code sorry this is my first time posting)

```
medians<-aggregate(FGPChange~convert,df,median)
df %>% 
ggplot(aes(x=convert, y=FGPChange, fill=convert)) +
geom_boxplot(fill='dark red') + 
theme_bw() +
theme(panel.border = element_blank(), 
    panel.grid.major = element_blank(),panel.grid.minor
 = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour =
     "black"))+
stat_summary(fun=median, geom="point",shape=18, size=3,
           color="red",fill="red")+
geom_text(data=medians,aes(label=FGPChange,y=FGPChange+6.00))+
```

Comment: Change to `label=FGPChange` to `label = round(FGPChange)`. If you need more help, please share some data reproducibly, like `dput(df[1:10, ])` for the first 10 rows (choose a suitable small subset to illustrate the problem).